# Chrome background fixed issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've set an background-image as fixed on a website page. On FF, IE, Safari everything works just fine, except in Chrome (Version 40.0.2214.115).

I know there are a lot of topics on this issue and I've tried to solve it using

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

amongst other solutions but none seemed to work.

[This is the example page](http://www.beeverlyfields.com/gallery)

Does anyone know a solution to this? Or maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hi it's very simple no need to add any webkit & media tag just follow below

steps I removed the background Url tag in below container
.content .container { /* background: url(http://beeverlyfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/bgBeeverly4.jpg); */

i added img src tag in class="container" and position as fixed and top=0

[image]

Now its working in chrome-40 and IE